# If both spawn() and fork() used in same project node js?

Tags: node.js, child-process

In my project, I have 2 different functions. Both results in pushing into two different queues.

1. First queue: for each item, I do `child_process.fork()` in order to send some data from child to parent.
2. Second queue: for each item, I do `child_process.spawn()`.

My questions are:

1. Is there any chance of issue will come because of using both fork and spawn methods of `child_process` in same project?
2. Do i need to concern about the number of CPU's? Because I am providing a limit to queue to take the data? Here i use 2 queues.
3. What about the performance if I use both?

Comment: They are basically the same thing, but fork() is "used specifically to spawn new Node.js processes". You shouldn't have a problem using both.

Comment: Thank you @Nicholas Kyriakides